# Можете объяснить, что происходит в цикле for? Не знаю что означает res += (num % 2 == 0). Как называется такой синтаксис?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 15, 17]
res = 0

for num in numbers:
    res += (num % 2 == 0)

print(res)
```

Comment: Тоже самое но без приведения `bool -> int`: `res += 1 - num % 2`.

Answer (score 2):

Выражение `num % 2 == 0` возвращает `True` или `False` в зависимости от того, чётное число или нет.
Если прибавить к числу типа `int` значение `True`, произойдёт то же самое, что если бы вы добавили единицу. То есть по сути `True = 1`, а `False = 0`.
Цикл перебирает каждое число из списка, и прибавляет True (единицу) к переменной `res`, если число четное и False (ноль), если нечетное.
В целом, программа считает количество четных чисел в списке.

Comment: "Как называется такой синтаксис?" :-)

Comment: Какое-то определенное название вряд ли есть. Называйте как хотите) Сложение типов int и bool например.

Comment: Я бы предложил "синтаксический сахар" ("синтаксические возможности, применение которых не влияет на поведение программы, но делает использование языка более удобным для человека" - Wikipedia). Ну, или "сокращённая форма записи"

Answer (score 0):

Даётся массив чисел и переменная, в которой будет содержаться количество четных чисел. Проходим циклом весь массив и на каждой итерации прибавляем 1, если это четное число посредством выражения `num % 2 == 0`, которое будет давать 0 или 1. Я бы назвал это *check-add in-place*

Эквивалентно этому:

```
 for num in numbers :
    if num % 2 == 0 :
        res += 1;
```